# Redirecting REST request using Servlets

Tags: java, rest, servlets, redirect

Here is my issue. I want to be able to receive a REST request at an url like 
`localhost:8080/API` to some other address like `example.app/API`, however I want to add some extra fields to the existing REST request like `uuid` and `user_id` which are generated by some Java class or extracted from another Rest service.

So for example I get following request:

```
GET /API/myfunc HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

And resend a request

```
GET /example.app/API?uuid=1231231231231&user_id=3 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

Now this is simple if its a `GET` request, but what if it's a `POST` request?

Is there a already made solution to this problem?

Comment: probably you want to do something like this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/ServletURLredirect.htm

Answer (score 1):

UrlRewriteFilter [1] might help you here.

Such a filter allows you to define advanced redirecting rules and gives you access to the request and response objects (e.g. you can use request.addParameter(...))

Check the `<run> element` and `<class-rule> element` sections from [2].

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

[2] http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html

Comment: The issue is I need to add two parameters generated from other classes. Can `UrlRewriteFilter` extract parameters from outside classes?

Comment: It depends on how do you initialise the other classes. Are you using  a DI framework?